voice.register(token) response null
import { Voice } from '@twilio/voice-react-native-sdk';

const voice = new Voice();

export async function initTelephony() {
try {
    // Ask for call permissions
    await triggerPermissions();
    try {
        const accessToken = await fetchTwilioAccessToken();
        console.log('accessToken----', accessToken);
        if (accessToken) {
            voice.register(accessToken)
                .then((response) =>
                    console.log('response----', response)
                )
                .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error registering voice:', error);
    }
    // Configre callkit on iOS
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        iOSConfigureCallkit();
    }

} catch (error) {
    console.log('initTelephony error: ', error)
}
}

response---- null
i need something in responce
i added my project in firebase and connected and cloud url configured with twilio server
i ref this documentation -- https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android
please can any one help here
i am using @twilio/voice-react-native-sdk: "^1.0.0",
